What is the Bregman projection of $\rho+\epsilon X$ onto the space of states?
Notation:
Let $S(X)=\operatorname{tr}[X\log X]$ for any $X\geq0$ be the von Neumann entropy and let $D_S(X,Y)=\operatorname{tr}[X\log X-X\log Y -X+Y]$ be the corresponding Bregman divergence (which is the quantum relative entropy up to the $-X+Y$).
Question:
For a weak perturbation $\tilde\rho=\rho+\epsilon X$ of a quantum state $\rho$ with a hermitian $X$ of norm one, what is the Bregman projection of $\tilde\rho$ onto the space of states? (i.e. the minimizing state $\sigma^\star=\operatorname{argmin}_{\sigma} D_S(\sigma,\tilde\rho)$ )
And in particular, is it (maybe just in linear order in $\epsilon$) simply the normalization $\frac{\tilde\rho}{\operatorname{tr}[\tilde\rho]}$?
